# Insert into where column count is different

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

In SQL Server 2005, I have a temp table #Table1 which holds data from a dynamic pivot based on day of month. The table will have 28,29,30 or 31 columns depending on month/year.
I then want to create another temp table #Table2 with  a static 31 columns (to add some data for report formatting) and append #Table1 into it with nulls in the extra columns.

I tried:

```
Select * into #Table2 from #Table1
```

but this does not work, it tells me that #Table2 already exists in the database. I know it does, I put it there!!

Or, is there a way to add column 29,30 and 31 to #Table 1 if I run the pivot in February
or 31 if I run it in June/September?

I hope this explains my dilemma and there is an easy solution. I'm not too smart at this!!

Comment: Why not just do a static pivot of 31 columns to create table 1, if having those extra columns is acceptable? Also, you can't use `SELECT ... INTO` for an existing table [`INTO` Clause](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188029.aspx): "creates a **new** table" (my emphasis). You need to use `INSERT ... SELECT` to insert into an existing table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add 29,30 and 31 as column names just like other dates in your pivot statement like:

```
SELECT 1,2,...,28,29,30,31
FROM table
PIVOT(SUM(aggregate column) FOR spreading column IN(1,2,...,28,29,30,31)) AS P;
```

and then you shouldn't use `Select * into` clause as it creates a new table. You should use following clause:

```
 insert into #Table2 
 select * from #Table1
```

Hope this helps!!!

Answer (score 0):

Hi Try this code before creating temp table #table1 and #table2 you should check tables are exist or not if exist then try to delete that and create as per your logic after final execution you should again delete both tables from the temp DB. Hope this code will helpful.
[image]

Comment: Posting code as an image is a remarkably unfriendly way to share - especially because SO has good code markup facilities. If you highlight a block of code and hit the `{}` button, it should turn on syntax highlighting in your answer (check the preview). That also means that others can then copy and paste from your answer.

Comment: My bad. My query had same posting problem that's why I used Image. otherwise I always reply with Query snippet. thank you.